# Kentico Smart Search Index - any way to read it with the API?

Tags: json, search, model-view-controller, kentico, typeahead

We need to get a search box autocomplete working based on Kentico search indexes, but half the site is in the CMS app pages, and half is in MVC. So the autocomplete webpart works on the CMS app pages, but not the MVC ones.

An option we're exploring is to use the Twitter Typeahead js library in both sides of the site, which requires the search terms to be in a json file.

So we'd like to be able to load the search index terms via the Kentico API and then write that out to a json file.

The SearchIndexInfo object doesn't seem to have a way to get the index's terms that it writes out to the index files.

**Update**

For clarification: We can do the search via the API, but the searchresultitems only return with the title and content fields, and they do not contain all the search terms that are stored in the index files.

For instance, a search index for a custom page type might build the index based on the DocumentName, Description, Location, City, Company Name, DesignCategory fields. All of those will be stored in the index somewhere, so how do we read the terms that are stored in the index?

Not just the results, which would only have DocumentName(title) and Description (content).

We're basically trying to convert the search index files into a json representation, not the search results.

Of course, if the SmartSearchDialog webpart just does its predictive search on only the title and content fields, then we would just go with that, but I believe the SmartSearchDialog does an actual search does it not?

thanks

Comment: Of course, if we can't do that, we could probably implement an ajax method to call an mvc action that does a search based on the terms the user has typed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roman's answer in the comments doesn't look like it would work, and in thinking about it some more we were perhaps trying to do something too complicated and weren't asking the right question maybe.

Instead of trying to replicate the search index in json for use by the twitter typeahead autocomplete, perhaps a better way to do it is to keep it simpler and just use the search results' title and content fields.

Then, in order to get additional fields into the content field of the search results ( such as project location ) we can then customize the search building code (CMSLoaderAttribute) to add the extra fields into the SearchDocument's Content field.

Answer (score 3):

There is API for it:

```
// Gets the search index
SearchIndexInfo index = SearchIndexInfoProvider.GetSearchIndexInfo("NewIndex");

if (index != null)
{
    // Prepares the search parameters
    SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters()
    {
        SearchFor = "home",
        SearchSort = "##SCORE##",
        Path = "/%",
        ClassNames = "",
        CurrentCulture = "EN-US",
        DefaultCulture = CultureHelper.EnglishCulture.IetfLanguageTag,
        CombineWithDefaultCulture = false,
        CheckPermissions = false,
        SearchInAttachments = false,
        User = (UserInfo)MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser,
        SearchIndexes = index.IndexName,
        StartingPosition = 0,
        DisplayResults = 100,
        NumberOfProcessedResults = 100,
        NumberOfResults = 0,
        AttachmentWhere = String.Empty,
        AttachmentOrderBy = String.Empty,
    };

    // Performs the search and saves the results into a DataSet
    System.Data.DataSet results = SearchHelper.Search(parameters);

    if (parameters.NumberOfResults > 0)
    {
        // The search found at least one matching result, and you can handle the results

    }
}
```

More details [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Smart+search#Smartsearch-Usinganindextosearchthroughtext).

Comment: Thanks Roman, but doesn't that just return the searchresultitems? The searchresultitems only return with the title and content fields right? not all the search terms that are stored in the index files? Or is that what the SmartSearchDialog does, does it only do the predictive/typeahead functionality on the title and content fields?

Comment: Smart search searches any field that is configured to be searchable in page type or object. I believe this is what smart search dialog as well as predictive search does.

Comment: Thanks Roman, but doesn't that just return the searchresultitems? The searchresultitems only return with the title and content fields right? not all the search terms that are stored in the index files? For instance, a search index for a custom page type might build the index based on the DocumentName, Description, Location, City, Company Name, DesignCategory fields. All of those will be stored in the index somewhere, so how do we read the terms that are stored in the index? 

Not just the results, which would only have DocumentName(title) and Description (content).

Comment: I believe you're referring to SearchService.GetSearchItems() method, correct. This method actually converts DataSet to collection of strongly typed objects - SearchResultItem. Have you checked what are other columns in the DataSet search API returns?

Comment: Thanks Roman, that sounds promising, I'll have a look into that one.

Comment: Actually Roman, it looks like GetSearchItems() isn't available to use, and it appears that it just returns the same data that SearchHelper.Search returns. What we really need is the rows stored in the index files, not the results. Then again, maybe what we were thinking about doing was too complicated, and we'll limit the typeahead to just documentname and description.